# Erro ao criar Windows Form no Visual Studio 2015 C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2015

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

criei um projeto vazio CLR ai fui em project >> add new item>> UI >> Windows Form
mas ele da esse erro ai, como resolver isso?

Comment: Vejo que você tem o ícone do codeblocks na barra inferior. Acho que ele é a sua resposta!

Comment: nao é mais facil fazer interface com o Visual Studio? Da pra fazer ela com o code block?